Когда Selenium открывает страницу, она долго загружается и приостанавливает работу кода
Страница загружается мгновенно, если я сам открываю её через браузер.
Если страница открывается драйвером Selenium'a, то она начинает загружаться 15-20 секунд. В это время работа кода останавливается, и приходится ждать окончания загрузки.
Я могу прервать загрузку страницы с помощью set_page_load_timeout(), но я хочу понять возможно ли остановить загрузку проще или какая моя ошибка приводит к наличию этой загрузки.
Страницы, на которых я заметил подобное поведение:
https://www.mlbb.ninja/statistics ,
https://crossoutdb.com/#preset=crafting.rarity=special.craftable=true.order=20desc.
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# browser.set_page_load_timeout(2)

try:
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get("https://www.mlbb.ninja/statistics")
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label='Win Rate']").click()
    time.sleep(2)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

finally:
    browser.quit()


Ты не пробовал на bs4 сделать?
Добавь больше заголовков  - это может помочь с долгой загрузкой
Слипы сделай больше если код не успевает за страницей( sleep или имеющийся в selenium Explicit Waits(почитай в доке))
Используя selenium попробуй куксы с браузера привязать
Решение с использованием request
import  requests
s = requests.Session()
head = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

r = s.get('https://www.mlbb.ninja/', cookies={'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.1.502207133.17129******; _ga_21X1D9MLS4=GS1.1.1712940200.1.1*********'},headers=head)
print(r.status_code)

page_stat_all_hero = s.get('https://www.mlbb.ninja/_next/data/F1o2w-nSCB8AWpAZt4WfN/index.json',headers=head)
print(page_stat_all_hero.text) #тут json в котором вся инфа о каждом герое (от id до pick_rate)

#-->тут ты допустим берешь все id и клепаешь ссылки на каждого героя, переходишь по ним и парсишь<--#

one_hero = s.get('https://www.mlbb.ninja/heroes/88',headers=head)
print(hero.text) #тута уже парсишь к примеру текущую статистику или инфу по скилам


как мне добавить заголовки ?
у меня есть список, но как их добавить я не знаю
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "Accept-Language": "en",  "Cache-Control": "max-age=0", "Connection": "keep-alive", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"

слипы и bs4 не будут работать пока не пройдет эта самая загрузка в 15-20 секунд

И так я потыкал этот сайт и там страничка подгружается из js скриптов, я не знаю что тебе нужно сделать, но я получил всех персонажей со страницы 'https://www.mlbb.ninja/statistics' (name , id ,link_photo и тд до pick_rate). Я думаю этого достаточно для дальнейших действий т.к на страницу отдельного перса можно перейти по его id. Добавь куки с браузера в селениум и должно заработать
